# difference between two tree merge and 3-way merge

Tags: git, merge

I'm reading about [git-read-tree](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree) and two kinds of merges are mentioned there: `two tree merge` and `3-way merge`. I'm trying to figure out what's the difference between them. I assume that with 3-way merge git checks how any particular chunk of code looked in a shared parent commit, checks whether any of the commits modified it and if only one commit modified the chunk git then applies it without conflict. Whereas with two tree commit git simply compares chunks between two trees and marks as conflicts those which are different between those commits. Is this assumption correct?

I've also googled `two tree merge` and there is nothing on the subject besides git doc.